# How can I connect my conda environment dependencies to poetry's pyproject.toml (or to poetry in general)?

Tags: pip, conda, python-packaging, python-poetry, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` that I regularly update using my conda virtual environment. I also have a `pyproject.toml` file, that, when it comes down to it, has a lot of dependencies. A lot.

I have to manually sift through scores of dependencies, hoping that one doesn't break in the pyproject during PyPI deployment.

...

Is there any easier way to transfer requirements from the requirements.txt file (or from your conda  environment) into Poetry, say, that can automatically add all the dev dependencies?

I've tried using the `cat` command to spit out my requirements.txt into `poetry add`, but sometimes, poetry throws errors and it becomes a pain to repeatedly add / delete.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. Maybe you could clarify what are the expected inputs and outputs of the processes you want to achieve.

Comment: You can create `requirements.txt` from `pyproject.toml` using `poetry export` command. Other way around I don't think it's possible. You need to use `poetry` as your primary package manager and then export `requirements.txt` snapshot when necessary.

Comment: Here is an example command how to export https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/f73e3efcd53f5ed0e59a302ae5b6ccbd3c20e8c3/Makefile#L103